# Django Authenticate against external SSO

Tags: django, django-views

Forgive me if the wording here is a bit odd. I have a fair amount of experience with python, but I'm pretty new to Django and still trying to get my sea legs.

I've inherited a `PHP` site from the former System admin at my new job, and I want to rework it into a django app to simplify/cleanup the code.

The PHP site is using `.htaccess` file with `Pubcookie` apache module for authentication (as well as some basic checks in the php code to ensure the user checks out against a database of authorized users, but that part i'm less concerned with), and looks like this:

```
AuthType SecureID
require valid-user
PubcookieAppID "name of the app"
```

In my `apache` configs, I have various pubcookie definitions.

```
LoadModule pubcookie_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_pubcookie.so
PubcookieGrantingCertFile /usr/local/pubcookie/keys/pubcookie_granting.cert
PubcookieSessionKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/akey.pem
PubcookieSessionCertFile /etc/ssl/certs/acert.pem
PubcookieLogin https://weblogin.domain.com/
PubcookieLoginMethod POST
PubcookieDomain .domain.com
PubcookieKeyDir /usr/local/pubcookie/keys/
PubcookieAuthTypeNames ADUserID null SecurID
```

My question is...How do I implement this sort of thing on the python end? I have looked at using `RemoteUserMiddleware`, or `PersistentRemoteUserMiddleware`.

But most of the information I have found for that doesn't go into great detail about how to actually point your app at the correct login page. The official documentation seems to stop at adding the middleware under middleware in the `settings.py` file in the django project.

It also bare's mentioning that the `weblogin.domain.com` is handled by another group that I don't have direct access to, and is not one of my servers so I can't really poke around there.

I realize this is...extremely broad, but any information that could point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

In an ideal scenario, I would like to be able to restrict different views to different authtypes, but I'd be happy to get anything working sensibly.

Answer (score 0):

So, For what it's worth. The answer was to use `pubcookie` with `apache` as normal. then use `RemoteUserMiddleware` or `PersistentRemoteeUserMiddleware` as expected. As it turns out you don't have to handle any outside configuration for the middleware, it just imports whats shoved at it.

Finally the piece I was really missing, information from `apache/pubcookie` authentication can be accessed with `request.META` library from inside `django` code